# Array bounds checking

Tags: arrays, c

It seems with arrays it's easy to get an off-by-one error:

```
short xar[2] = {};
for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(xar)/sizeof(*xar); ++i) {
    xar[i-1]=i*i;
    printf("Element i = %d\n", xar[i]);
}
```

> Element i = 0 
> Element i = 0 
> Element i = -9272

Is there a good way to check for the out-of-bounds case? Or how is something like this usually done (it seems writing out of bound array values would be super easy to do!)

Comment: Ideally, by being careful and not doing that in the first place.  There are lots of tools that add checking at runtime, but they are generally compiler/OS dependent.

Comment: `xar[i-1]=i*i;`: when `i` is `0`, you access an element out of bounds.

Comment: `i <= `: array indices go from `0..n-1` so you access the last element in the loop out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

C as a language does not provide any provisions for bounds-checking beyond "keep track of it yourself". So there is not really a better solution in general other than being careful. There do exist programs like [ASAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) which can help detect such bugs at runtime though.

Comment: +1 for ASan, but GCC will also catch OP's particular bad example code at compile time (with `-Wall -Werror` options, which of course should always be enabled during development of any new code).  See: https://godbolt.org/z/9vWePx

Comment: @JohnZwinck good point! Now if only it could help out in the case of something dynamically allocated :(